# Loading dynamic images in Angular with webpack

Tags: image, angular, typescript, dynamic, webpack

We are using Webpack 1 with Angular 2 with typescript. In our app we would like to specify an image to be loaded in the typescript file dynamically.

For example, we have 10+ images (svg) in our pre-processed folder structure:

```
src\content\images\image1.svg
src\content\images\image2.svg
etc..
```

In the angular component html file we have the image element with the src binding:

```
<img [src]="_imgSrc">
```

In the type script file we set the correct url dynamically based on some criteria:

```
private _imgSrc: string;
public ngOnInit(): void {
    // Some logic...
    if (true) {
        this._imgSrc = './../../../content/images/image2.svg';
    }
    else {
        this._imgSrc = './../../../content/images/image1.svg';
    }
    // In real code, the file name will come from a typescript object returned from a web api call
```

We have configured webpack to use file loader for loading images:

```
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico|svg|wav|mp3)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
    },
```

In all current scenarios (apart from this one), we specify the image path in the html file, e.g

```
<img src="./../../../content/images/image2.svg">
```

and these images are copied to the proper output folder, and the path in the typescript file is set to the output folder, so we know our webpack file loader is set up correctly for the standard static approach.

The issue we have with this more dynamic approach:

1. Webpack does not emit the images to the final image folder:
   assets/images
2. The URL in the typescript file is not converted to the output
   image folder.

Is it possible for webpack to find the required images via the path in the typescript file? If so, how do we do this? If not, is there an alternative approach anyone has used for dynamically loading images based on some criteria in typescript?

Comment: I don't think this counts as an official solution, but when I've run up against this issue in the past the workaround I've done is to put the images you want to bundle inside a div inside the template with display:none or visibility:hidden.  You can then call the file paths in your component and the files will be there.  probably not the most scalable solution, but it's worked for me

Comment: @chairmanmow yep we have taken a similar approach. We have created a dedicated image component in angular that has all the images listed in tags<img src="./image1.svg *ngId="counterTypeId === 1">...then we are using *ngif to control whether the image is displayed, the actual id of the image is passed into the component via @Input(). I have checked and the component only requests the single image from the network that it needs, not all the images. Thanks.